# XmlException: Text node cannot appear in this state. Line 1, position 1

Tags: c#, xml, encoding, utf-8

Before I get into the issue, I'm aware there is another question that sounds exactly the same as mine. However, I've tried that solution (using Notepad++ to encode the xml file as UTF-8 (without BOM) ) and it doesn't work.

```
XmlDocument namesDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument factionsDoc = new XmlDocument();
namesDoc.LoadXml(Application.persistentDataPath + "/names.xml");
factionsDoc.LoadXml(Application.persistentDataPath + "/factions.xml");
```

Above is the code I have problems with. I'm not sure what the problem is.

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?>
<factions>
        <major id="0">
...
```

Above is a section of the XML file (the start of it - names.xml is also the same except it has no 'id' attribute). The file(s) are both encoded in UTF-8 - in the latest notepad++ version, there is no option of "encode in UTF-8 without BOM" afaik UTF-8 is the same as UTF-8 without BOM.

Does anyone have any idea what the cause may be? Or am I doing something wrong/forgetting something? :/

Comment: could the issue be that I created it originally as a .txt file through notepad then converted to xml? ._.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what software to use to create the XML file? (I am assuming once its created I can edit it freely in notepad++? As I've done that before elsewhere)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are receiving an error because the `.LoadXml()` method expects a string argument that contains the XML *data*, not the location of an XML *file*. If you want to load an XML file then you need to use the `.Load()` method, not the `.LoadXml()` method.

Comment: Could it be that simple? o_O Will it not complain about the leading whitespace?

Comment: As you posted this I had worked it out myself haha. Thanks though! 
@Tomalak yes it was haha. There is also no leading whitespace.