# Got Unhandled Exception :: System.Xml.XmlException: Text node cannot appear in this state

Tags: c#

```
 using System;
 using System.Xml;

 public class program
 {

         public static void Main(string[] args)
         {
             string inp=Console.ReadLine();
             string outp=UserProgramCode.GetNodeByName(inp);
             Console.Write(outp);
         }

 }
 public class UserProgramCode
 {

     public static string GetNodeByName(string input1)
     {

         XmlDocument xd= new XmlDocument();

         xd.LoadXml(@"input1");


         XmlNodeList nodeList = xd.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");


        string output="";

        foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
        {

                output+=node["FirstName"].InnerText;
                output+=node["LastName"].InnerText;
        }
        return output;

    }
 }
```

Comment: And the question is?

Answer (score 1):

see [XmlException: Text node cannot appear in this state. Line 1, position 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33331829/xmlexception-text-node-cannot-appear-in-this-state-line-1-position-1)

Gord Thompson :
You are receiving an error because the .LoadXml() method expects a string argument that contains the XML data, not the location of an XML file. If you want to load an XML file then you need to use the .Load() method, not the .LoadXml() method.